# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'label')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'label')" when I click on text field of auto-complete (material-ui based).

```
<Autocomplete
    id="free-solo-demo"
    freeSolo
    options={ContactList.map((contact) => contact.first_name)}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

I have list of contacts in "ContactList". But when I click on text field it gives me error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'label')".

Comment: you are reading `ContactList` not `label` where is it? fix could be `options={ContactList && ContactList.map((contact) => contact.first_name)}`

Comment: It is not working. I did not get it. Why I will require "ContactList &&" ? Can you tell me why it is giving me error about "label" ? I will be thankful to you. :)

Comment: okhy.. I resolved this error. The error was happening because in my contactList I had a null value. Now I fill that and now it is working fine.